# Why "access denied" always alerts

Tags: javascript

I have a code that checks if you are 18 years old:

```
let age = prompt("How old are you?")

function chk(age) {
  age = (age > 18) ? alert("Access allowed") : alert("Access denied");
}
chk()
if (age < 18) {
  let c = confirm("Are your parent allowed?");
  if (c) {
    alert("ok")
  } else {
    alert("than bye")
  }
} else {
  alert("Bye")
}
```

But for some reason, access always denied. Why?

Comment: Your function chk(age) is being called without an argument, in JS terms with the parameter `undefined`. So, chk(undefined) will try to compare undefined > 18, which is false, and hence it goes to `alert('access denied');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `chk()` function without passing an argument for age, which means age would be `undefined` inside the function, now `undefined > 18` will always be false, hence the alert of `Access Denied`

you could use `chk(age)` to prevent the above problem

```
let age = prompt("How old are you?")

function chk(age) {
    (age > 18) ?  alert("Access allowed") : alert("Access denied"); // you don't have to reassign since alert does not return any value
}
chk(age);

if (age < 18) {
 //.. remaining code
}
```

OR do not use the variable `age` as argument to the `chk` function, which masks the global age

```
let age = prompt("How old are you?")

function chk() { //without the age parameter, now the global age variable will be used inside the function
    (age > 18) ?  alert("Access allowed") : alert("Access denied"); // DO NOT reassign age in this case, as the global age would be rewritten
}
chk()
    if (age < 18) {
        let c = confirm("Are your parent allowed?");
        if (c) {
            alert("ok")
        } else {
            alert("than bye")
        }
    }else {
        alert("Bye")
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but an alternative way of writing your code without involving any variables. I also "simplified" your `if`-clause-structure, since there were two "no" branches which effectively led to the same result. In my `if`-clause the "OR"-operator `||` will cause the `confirm()` function to be called *only* when the first condition (age>18) is *not* met.

```js
if (     prompt("How old are you?") > 18 
     || confirm("You are underage.\nDo your parents consent?")) {
  alert("ok")
    // execute all the code for authorized users here
} else {
  alert("Bye, bye")
}
```

Comment: Would the downlvoter please explain why they downvoted?